# Determine $2$ missing digits for modulo $11$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

### An account number verification system works as follows:

All digits in a 10-digit account number all multiplied by following weights:

$$(6 \ 3 \ 7 \ 9 \ 10 \ 5 \ 8 \ 4 \ 2 \ 1)$$

Resulting numbers are summed and divided by $11$. The result must be $0$.

Example:

Account number: $1111111111$

Sum: $1 \cdot 6 + 1 \cdot 3 + 1 \cdot 7 + 1 \cdot 9 + 1 \cdot 10 + 1 \cdot 5 + 1 \cdot 8 + 1 \cdot 4 + 1 \cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 1$

Result: $55$

$55 \bmod{11} = 0$: Check OK

---

### Goal:

I need to determine $2$ out of $10$ digits ($8$ are known) on positions $6$ and $7$.
Example:

```
$21942xy925$
```

where $x$ can only be $8$ or $9$ and $y$ can be any integer.

How can I calculate the correct values for $x$, $y$ without resorting to brute-force methods?

Comment: Try computing the sum as you would for any account number, but leaving $x$ and $y$ as variables in that sum. How can you then choose $x$ and $y$ such that the sum is divisible by $11$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It amounts to solving $\ \color{#c00}8y \equiv -k - 5x\!\pmod{11}\,$ for $\,x =8\,$ or $\,9.\,$ and $\,k=$ sum from other digits.

Notice that  $\,{\rm mod}\ 11\!:\,\ 1/\color{#c00}8 \equiv 12/{-}3 = -4,\,$ so $\, y \equiv 4k+20x\equiv 4k-2x \equiv \smash[b]{\underbrace{4k+6}_{\large x=8},\ \underbrace{4k+4}_{\large x=9}} $

The same technique works for other unknown digits.

Comment: Simple yet complete, thanks!